# Again on using interlocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.timers.timer

I read a lot of answers on this point but I did not found the solution yet.

I have a class with a counter attribute having a problem with cached values. Even volatile don't seems to work:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Timer _timer;
    private int _threadsCounter = 0;
    public StreamWriter Tracer { get; set; }

    public MyClass() {
        _timer = new Timer(1000.0 * 10);
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        HashSet<Task> taskPool = new HashSet<Task>();
        try {
            if (Tracer != null) Tracer.WriteLine("[{0}] onTimer start. Current threads counter is {1}.", DateTime.Now, _threadsCounter);
            if (_threadsCounter >= 10) return;

            // create parallel tasks
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                // limit on the max num of parallel processing but the counter remains unchanged during this timer event!!!
                if (_threadsCounter >= 10) break;

                var timeout = (30 + i * 2);
                var task = Task.Run(() => {
                        var localCounter = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadsCounter);
                        try {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeout * 1000);
                        }
                        finally {
                            System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadsCounter);
                        }
                    });
                taskPool.Add(task);
            }

        }
        finally {
            if (Tracer != null) 
                Tracer.WriteLine("[{0}] onTimer end. Created {1} tasks. Current threads counter is {2}.", DateTime.Now, taskPool.Count, _threadsCounter);
        }
    }
```

Well, it seems that the onTimer caches the _threadsCounter variable as the output is:

```
[14:10:47] onTimer start. Current threads counter is 0.
[14:10:47] onTimer end. Created 8 tasks. Current threads counter is 0.

[14:10:57] onTimer start. Current threads counter is 8.
[14:10:57] onTimer end. Created 8 tasks. Current threads counter is 8.

[14:11:07] onTimer start. Current threads counter is 16.
[14:11:07] onTimer end. Created 0 tasks. Current threads counter is 16.

[14:11:17] onTimer start. Current threads counter is 15.
[14:11:17] onTimer end. Created 0 tasks. Current threads counter is 15.

[14:11:37] onTimer start. Current threads counter is 4.
[14:11:37] onTimer end. Created 8 tasks. Current threads counter is 4.

[14:11:47] onTimer start. Current threads counter is 8.
[14:11:47] onTimer end. Created 8 tasks. Current threads counter is 8.

[14:11:57] onTimer start. Current threads counter is 16.
[14:11:57] onTimer end. Created 0 tasks. Current threads counter is 16.
```

Why do I arrive to 16?
I solved the problem by changing a bit the code:

```
var localCounter = _threadsCounter;
...
if ((localCounter + taskPool.Count) >= 10) break;
```

But why this behavior?

Comment: It looks like you are checking `_threadsCounter` in your loop, but the actual code that changes `_threadsCounter` is in your task that is being spun up on a different thread. So of course your `_threadsCounter` isn't incremented the next time through your loop. The task you started in the last iteration probably hasn't even started up yet.

Comment: Perhaps you've gotten lucky with the "fix".  Really though if `_threadsCounter` is a shared resource amongst multiple threads, you need synchronized access on ALL reads/writes to this shared resource.

Comment: @ChrisO: Not luck, `taskPool.Count` is actually getting updated when tasks are added to the pool. In other words, in the loop. While `_threadsCounter` isn't. It's only updated when the OS gets around to actually starting those threads (which may be after the loop has completed).

Comment: @MattBurland You're right! I didn't think task were still pending. Thank you

Comment: @MattBurland Got it, thanks.  Still needs synchronized access on `_threadsCounter` which is missing in two spots.

Comment: @ChrisO why do you think I need to sync the reading access to `_threadCounter`? Reading is atomic in the line `if ((_threadCounter + taskPool.Count) >= 10) break;` and no problems occurs if the counter changes in the middle, isn't it?

Comment: If the `OnTimer` runs once, then you're good.  My mistake was assuming that it was getting called multiple times during the lifetime of a `MyClass` instance.

Comment: @ChrisO yes, it runs multiple times, but I still don't get the reason for your sync. May you kindly explain it?

Comment: OK, at the bottom of the `for` loop, are you guaranteeing that the tasks/threads are no longer running, and thus cannot access the `_threadCounter` var?  If the tasks can still run in parallel while the rest of the `OnTimer` method is running, then you can have problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.Run` doesn't start the task immediately. It adds the task to the thread pool queue and returns.

In your case, the whole `for` loop is executed before the new tasks start running, so nothing changes `_threadsCounter`. That's why `volatile` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively testing for the number of tasks that have actually started and got as far as incrementing the counter. That takes a little while - so basically you're creating all 8 tasks and starting them, *then* they're incrementing the counter... by which time it's too late to notice that you've got more than 10.

The better solution would be to increment the counter *before* you start the task:

```
// Increment the counter in expectation of starting a task
var localCounter = Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadsCounter);
if (localCounter >= 10)
{
    // Ah, we're not going to start a task after all, so undo
    // the increment
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadsCounter);
    break;
}
else 
{
    // Start a task, which will decrement the counter at the end.
    // (You could add the "decrement" bit as a continuation, even...)
}
```